# Запустить\развернуть\свернуть программу по rightAlt

Tags: hotkeys, autohotkey

Подскажите, я нуб. Хочу запускать, разворачивать, сворачивать программу по rightAlt.

Гуглил и пробовал сам,
 условие

- Если программа 1 не запущена, то запускаем ее
- Если она запущена, то выводим на передний план
- Если она на переднем плане, то сворачиваем в панель задач
- Если она свернута, то разворачиваем ее

  sc138::
  Process, Exist,Dynalist.exe
  If !ErrorLevel
  Run , C:\Users\Reifwp\AppData\Local\Dynalist\Dynalist.exe
  else {
  WinActive("ahk_exe Dynalist.exe")
  WinGet, state, MinMax
  if (state != -1)
  WinMinimize
  else {
  WinRestore
  WinActivate
  }
  }
  Return

В настоящий момент, прога запускается по правому альту, если не запущена, то выходит на передний план, сворачивается, если запущена, но не разворачивается,если свернута

Answer (score 1):

УРА! Получилось у меня , RightAlt

```
    sc138::
WinExist("ahk_exe Dynalist.exe")
WinGet, state, MinMax
if (state != -1)
WinMinimize
else {
WinRestore
WinActivate
} ;
Process, Exist,Dynalist.exe
If !ErrorLevel
Run , C:\Users\Reifwp\AppData\Local\Dynalist\Dynalist.exe
```